# Issue with resizing body after an animation in css

Tags: css, animation, resize

I have a problem with resizing my screen after an animation which shows a button. I have this animation from this site: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ so it's not mine. Anyway it looks like this:

```
.bounceInRight {
-webkit-animation-name: bounceInRight;
animation-name: bounceInRight;
}

@keyframes bounceInRight {
from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
}

from {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
}

60% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
}

75% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
}

90% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
}

to {
-webkit-transform: none;
transform: none;
}
}
```

On PC works perfectly. But on the phone (I'm making a hybrid app using phonegap) you can scroll this site because this moved object leaves some space behind himself. I made a simulation in chrome (pressing the combination  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and choosing mobile view) what exactly happens what you can see in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgVGy.png). The blue margin is default size of a screen. After this animation screen resizes to the size of the yellow margin (and I don't want it) and stays like that. But when I resize whole page (green arrows) it kind of refresh itself and then problem dissapears (everything resizes back to the size of the blue margin). And my question is how can I avoid this?
I added this animation to my object using jquery (after clicking on another button):

```
$("#anotherbutton").click(function() {
$("#buttonnext").addClass("animated slideInRight");
});
```

I'm starting with programing so please be patient. And sorry for any english mistakes.

Comment: Can you paste your #buttonnext CSS code?

Comment: #buttonnext {
 display: none;
 right: 5%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 45%;
 width: 30%;
 top: 55%;
 left: 70%;
 background-color: #525252;
 color: white;
 border: 5px solid white;
 border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
 font-size : 7vw;
 font-family: Digitalt;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
 z-index: 3;
}

Comment: I'd love to help, but unless you create a [mcve] of your problem, where I could ***experience your bug and inspect the code of relevant elements***, I'm in the dark. Could you create a fiddle or add to the example above using the snippet tool? (Use the `<>` button to build a snippet).

Comment: I've created a fiddle on jsfiddle.net but there everything works perfectly. So there is no sense to send you this.